# Ссылка на возврат к главной странице из внутренних на django

Tags: python, django

прошу не пинать за вопрос, если есть где почитать, дайте ссылку, моя проблема в данный момент в том, что в шаблон передаются

ссылка на главную, в виде 127.0.0.1:8000

есть вторая ссылка в виде 127.0.0.1:8000/inner

 когда находишься на странице inner, ссылка на главную не отображается корректно.

 головной url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
]
```

main.url  (на ненужные импорты просьба не обращать внимание, позже почищу)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
# from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('inner/', views.inner, name='in_page'),
    # path(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

main.views

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *


top_menu = TopMenu.objects.all()
why_client_choice_us = WhyClientsChoiceUs.objects.all()
main_page_dark_slider = MainDarkSlider.objects.all()
last_slide = main_page_dark_slider.count()

#  Передает данные в главную страницу
index_dict = {'topmenu': top_menu, 'why_client_choice_us': why_client_choice_us,
              'main_page_slider': main_page_dark_slider, 'last_slide': last_slide}

#  Передает данные в рядовые страницы
page_dict = {'topmenu': top_menu, 'why_client_choice_us': why_client_choice_us,
              'main_page_slider': main_page_dark_slider, 'last_slide': last_slide}


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', index_dict)


def inner(request):
    return render(request, 'main/fragments/inner_page_fragments/inner_main_page_layout.html', page_dict)
```

И в итоге когда находишься на главной 127.0.0.1:8000

Все ссылки корректные

[image: Ссылки с главной страницы]

[image: Ссылки с внутренней страницы]

Как видно из скрина, если находиться на странице inner, и навести на эту же вкладку, то добавляется еще ссылка inner и получается 127.0.0.1/inner/inner, а ссылка О КОМПАНИИ должна вести на главную, а она не работает.

КОллеги подскажите, как с ссылками разобраться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

что бы не ставить пути самостоятельно и не ловить проблем с лишними или пропущенными `/`
используй в шаблоне `{% url "home" %}`, `{% url "inner" %}`
а если передаешь путь внутри Python кода, то используй reverse (подробней - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/)

Используя эти функции будет легче конфигурировать урлы, особенно если будут использоваться дополнительные параметры в url конфиг

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, в шаблоне html  нужно было ставить начальный слеш, для того что бы ссылки были абсолютными. Вопрос закрыт